# Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in()

Tags: error-handling, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress Plugin. While using (wp_insert_post) I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in /home/designs/public_html/WP/wp-includes/post.php on line 2185
```

Here is the file on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/YETGT4dK This file is included in main plugin file.

Thank you !

---

The relevant section of the pastebin is

```
if(isset($_POST['save_coupons']) and $_POST['save_coupons']=='yes'){


    //lots of stuff

    /*
     * Inserting New Coupon as Post
    */
    $post = array();
    $post['post_status']   = 'publish';
    $post['post_type']     = 'coupons';
    $post['post_title']    = $title;
    $post['post_content']  = $description;

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

    //lots more stuff


}//endif
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `is_user_logged_in` is a pluggable function, and is therefore loaded *after* this plugin logic is called. The solution is to make sure that you don't call this too early. This can be done by wrapping this logic in a function and calling it from 'init'

```
function rizwan_insert_coupons()
{
    if(isset($_POST['save_coupons']) and $_POST['save_coupons']=='yes'){


        //lots of stuff

        /*
         * Inserting New Coupon as Post
        */
        $post = array();
        $post['post_status']   = 'publish';
        $post['post_type']     = 'coupons';
        $post['post_title']    = $title;
        $post['post_content']  = $description;

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

        //lots more stuff


    }
}
add_action('init', 'rizwan_inert_coupons');
```